# PHP pushing submit button takes two times to initiate code

Tags: php

Every time it takes two clicks on the submit button to get the code to go, also just randomly it was triggering different codes that are setup the same way but with different names for the input and inside the `$_POST`. Am I using the `$_POST` right by setting the name of the input to the same thing?

here is the code

```
<?php                       
//If submit form was clicked
if(isset($_POST['intro'])) {
    //Server side validation for security purposes
    if($userpoints >= 100 AND $intro == 0 AND $lifeonmarsalbum == 0) {
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET points = points - 100 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET intro = 1 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <?php
    if ($userpoints >= 100 AND $intro == 0 AND $lifeonmarsalbum == 0) {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="intro" value="100pts">';
    } elseif ($intro == 1 OR $lifeonmarsalbum == 1) {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts" disabled title="You already earned this track!">';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts" disabled title="You need at least 100 points for this download">';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: By using `UPDATE...WHERE user_name='$username'`, you missed the point of using `MySQLi`. Suggest to use `$stmt=mysqli_prepare("UPDATE...WHERE user_name=?");mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$username);`.

Comment: Ya if you can't tell I am completely new to PHP and MySQLi, literally just started using it two days ago to build a point system with my website. So everything I use is just what I am learning from the internet. I got the mysqli code from W3Schools

Comment: Wow, w3school has a VERY bad reputation in SO. People even built [a website](http://w3fools.com) to "downvote" it. Reading [the guide on PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) might be better.

Comment: ok I will definitely look into that then, W3Schools is usually what comes up when I do a google search, but I will start referring to the guide from now on

Comment: So I have tried a ton of different things with the code and it still has not fixed the problem. When I make an edit to the code and then try it, it will work on one click one time but then it goes back to how it was.

Answer (score 2):

You only output a `name="intro"` submit button when that first line of `if()` clauses is met. Most likely the first time you load this page, that condition isn't met, so there's no `intro` button. After the first submitt, the condition IS met, and you get `name="intro"` in the form, and the submit then "starts" working.

Comment: OP says he clicks on submit button two times

Comment: yes, and? click one, no intro, so nothing happens, except that intro submit button is generated, so the 2nd click "works". OP didn't say there's no form submission, just that there's two clicks.

Comment: `click one` on what? OP says `two clicks on the submit`...sorry, it is just for clarifying me

Comment: I know it is working because the other two options are disabled buttons, so the only one not disabled has the name

Comment: I deleted the if statements and still got the same issue. Also if I click it once and then click a different submit button it still runs the button that was clicked first. I have multiple of these on the page could that be what is causing the problem?